# C# struct behavior based on architecture

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, struct

I have a question regarding either feeding multiple structs into a method depending on compile architecture, 
or about properly laying out the Thread_Basic_Information struct so I can just use a single struct for the same method regardless of x64/x86 (see for reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have confirmed it working fine on x86, and if I manually switch out the struct's it will also work for x64.
However I've recently tried to change my approach from just copy-pasting a ton of functions to trying to recycle my code.

I'm having an extremely difficult time trying to find either precise information on the struct in question which I can use in C# to make it compatible regardless of x86/x64, or feeding 2 different struct's into the same method depending on architecture.

Perhaps StructLayout pack size? however I am not familiar with that attribute.

I'm hoping there might be a way I can generic this, such as if IntPtr.Size == 8 then use 64bit struct, else use 32bit struct. However short of copy-pasting code with a minor rename, I'm hoping there may be a way to do this with generics?

Code:

Method used to create the thread:

```
public IRemoteThread Create(IntPtr address, bool isStarted = true)
{
    //Create the thread
    var thr = ThreadHelper.CreateRemoteThread(Process.Handle, address, IntPtr.Zero, ThreadCreationFlags.Suspended)
    //Acquire desired information from the thread
    var ret = ThreadHelper.NtQueryInformationThread(thr);

    // Do other stuff 
    return result;
}
```

Support method for querying the thread info we desire:

```
public static ThreadBasicInformation NtQueryInformationThread(SafeMemoryHandle threadHandle)
{
    // Check if the handle is valid
    HandleManipulator.ValidateAsArgument(threadHandle, "threadHandle");

    // Create a structure to store thread info
    var info = new ThreadBasicInformation();

    // Get the thread info
    var ret = Nt.NtQueryInformationThread(threadHandle, 0, ref info, MarshalType<ThreadBasicInformation>.Size,
        IntPtr.Zero);

    // If the function succeeded
    if (ret == 0)
        return info;

    // Else, couldn't get the thread info, throws an exception
    throw new ApplicationException($"Couldn't get the information from the thread, error code '{ret}'.");
}
```

32bit struct used in the above method:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ThreadBasicInformation
{
    public uint ExitStatus;

    public IntPtr TebBaseAdress;

    public int ProcessId;

    public int ThreadId;

    public uint AffinityMask;

    public uint Priority;

    public uint BasePriority;
}
```

x64 variant of the same struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ThreadBasicInformation64
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint ExitStatus;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr TebBaseAdress;

    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public int ProcessId;

    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public int ThreadId;

    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public uint AffinityMask;

    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public uint Priority;

    [FieldOffset(44)]
    public uint BasePriority;
}
```

EDIT:

C declaration I found:

```
typedef LONG KPRIORITY; 

typedef struct _CLIENT_ID { 
   HANDLE UniqueProcess; 
   HANDLE UniqueThread; 
} CLIENT_ID; 
typedef CLIENT_ID *PCLIENT_ID; 

typedef struct _THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION 
{ 
   NTSTATUS                ExitStatus; 
   PVOID                   TebBaseAddress; 
   CLIENT_ID               ClientId; 
   KAFFINITY               AffinityMask; 
   KPRIORITY               Priority; 
   KPRIORITY               BasePriority; 
} THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PTHREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

Comment: I don't see that you need different structs 32 and 64 but systems. The affinity is IntPtr surely. Where is the C declaration for the struct.

Comment: Submitted an edit with the only useful C declaration I have found after hours of scouring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premise of your question is wrong because you have mistranslated the structs. Once you translate them correctly you will find that you can use a single declaration of the struct in your C# code and the compiler will lay it out correctly for all target architectures.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CLIENT_ID 
{
    public IntPtr UniqueProcess;
    public IntPtr UniqueThread;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public int ExitStatus;
    public IntPtr TebBaseAdress;
    public CLIENT_ID ClientId;
    public IntPtr AffinityMask;
    public int Priority;
    public int BasePriority;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your help solved my problems. It would seem I may need to seek out reinforcement of my knowledge of C/PP before I proceed much further down this road, but in any event I appreciate your help.